# how to change the header text of table in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to learn **Ui-grid** from this link

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/101_intro.

I make a simple example of ui-grid in plunker..Actually the table header **takes first object property name** .I need to give other name instead of property name.Example I need my first columns name should  "First" and "second" without changing the array of objects here is my code

https://plnkr.co/edit/s0NUaL15W4Q95WXGeQK5?p=preview

```
angular.module('app',['ngTouch', 'ui.grid']).controller('MainCtrl',function($scope){

  $scope.data=[{
    name:'abc',
    lastname:'hrt'

  },{
    name:'pqr',
      lastname:'oiu'

  },{
    name:'lqm',
      lastname:'ytu'

  }]

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see your solution here
https://plnkr.co/edit/cDaeiNmWIvQ0NLoWxYKX?p=preview

you need to set Options to ui-grid, so you can set displayName in columnDefs

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
     columnDefs: [
       {field: 'name', displayName:'First'},
       {field: 'lastname', displayName:'Second'}
       ]
 };
```

Comment: oops sorry one minute @user944513

Answer (score 0):

use grid option 'columnDefs'

```
angular.module('app',['ngTouch', 'ui.grid']).controller('MainCtrl',function($scope){

  $scope.datas=[{
    name:'abc',
    lastname:'hrt'

  },{
    name:'pqr',
      lastname:'oiu'

  },{
    name:'lqm',
      lastname:'ytu'

  }];
  $scope.gridOptions = {
     columnDefs: [
       { name:'First', field: 'name' },
       { name:'Second', field: 'lastname' }],
    data : $scope.datas
  };

})
```

html

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  {{3+5}}
    <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" ></div>

</div>
```